# sites stops displaying after DateTime::createFromFormat

Tags: php, datetime

i have a section of code

```
    $date = dateTime::createFromFormat('Y-m-d', $sel_event['date']);
    $output_date = $date->format('F j, Y');
```

when i run the page on my localhost server it works fine. but if i upload it to my linux bluehost server it wont display anything else on the entire site after the line of code before that. when i comment those lines out everything displays perfect.. heres more of the code. any one who can help me, thanks in advance.

```
    <div id="headliner">
    <h2><?php echo $sel_event['title'] . " At " . $sel_event['venue']; ?></h2>
    <?php 
    $date = dateTime::createFromFormat('Y-m-d', $sel_event['date']);
    $output_date = $date->format('F j, Y');
    ?>
    <h2><?php echo $sel_event['hotel'] . " | " . $output_date; ?></h2>
    </div><!-- close #headliner -->
```

Comment: Look at the error logs. I bet you just have too old php.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your script is dying probably due to fatal error when calling a datetIme. [DatTime](http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.createfromformat.php) is PHP 5.3 >= function.  Check the PHp version on your server

Answer (score 0):

`DateTime::createFromFormat()` is only available in PHP >= 5.3.0, you might want to try running `phpinfo();` on your host to see what version they are running.

Comment: would you happen to know an alternative function i could use? im fairly new to php. thanks for the info